# Split a string from last comma if character count exceed 20 C#

Tags: c#

I have a string which contains a address. Sometimes character count is exceed 20. Then I want to split it to two string from the last comma before coming 20.

```
string address = "address1, address2, address3, address4.";
```

This contains 39 characters which exceeds 20 character count. 
Then I want to split it from **comma** that comes after **address2**

```
string addr1 = "address1, address2,";
string addr2 = "address3, address4.";
```

**Updated :**
What I have tried so far. This split from last comma in the string. This is not the correct way every time.

```
    string address = rankList[k].ADDRESS;
    if (address.Length  > 20) {

        int idx = address.LastIndexOf(',');

        if (idx != -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(address.Substring(0, idx)); 
            Console.WriteLine(address.Substring(idx + 1));
        }

    }
```

Comment: To find the index of the comma you need to split on, you'll have to write something like `address.Substring(0, 20).LastIndexOf(',')`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_Char_System_Int32_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.8)

> Reports the zero-based index of the last occurrence of a specified
>   string within the current String object. The search starts at a
>   specified character position and proceeds backward toward the
>   beginning of the string. A parameter specifies the type of comparison
>   to perform when searching for the specified string.

StartIndex parameter : The search starting position. The search proceeds from startIndex toward the beginning of this instance.

```
    string address = "address1, address2, address3, address4.";

    if (address.Length > 20)
    {           
        var lastCommaPosition = address.LastIndexOf(',', 20);

        var address1 = address.Substring(0, lastCommaPosition+1);
        var address2 = address.Substring(lastCommaPosition+1, address.Length - (lastCommaPosition+1));
    }
```